# Swift project is larger than I expect

Tags: ios, memory, swift, ios8

My project has 4 frameworks and 31 (31 language) custom keyboard extensions. When I compile it, it takes 98 mb of internal device memory.

So I decided to take a look why so much. I found my project in the device folder.

[image]

Folder Plugins takes 38 mb, and folder Frameworks takes 42 mb.

[image]

[image]

In Frameworks folder is 4 my frameworks and 8 Swift's frameworks, that you can see at picture above

[image]

Each my framework contain the same 8 Swift's frameworks. Can I somehow add this swift frameworks only once?

It's not all. In Plugins folder is my custom keyboard extensions folders. I have 200 images added into one of my module(framework), and referenced that into each extension(because they need that images for building keyboard). But in project folder each extension folder has that images. It takes lots of memory.

So... Can I  somehow add images only once (not for each custom keyboard extension)? And can I add swift frameworks only once(not for each my framework and project too)?

**Edit:**

I undersnad that each custom keyboard extension is like separate program. So maby they realy need to copy that images into each extension.

Comment: At least all that duplication should compress well so the download size will be reasonable. But this does help explain why seemingly simple apps seem to take up so much space on my phone.

Comment: Swift is currently in BETA.  So I would think Apple would address these concerns when it comes to deployment.

Comment: Have you looked in the .app package to check the final result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now it is not necessary to have extension per language, so now it is not a big deal. You should use 1 extension for all languages, or a least for group of languages.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like this is due to the measures taken to achieve compatibility guarantees.

> ... Xcode embeds a small Swift runtime library within your app’s bundle. Because the library is embedded, your app uses a consistent version of Swift that runs on past, present, and future OS releases.

It is interesting that you're seeing it in each one of your frameworks. This statement seems to suggest that the framework does not include the runtime libraries.

> While your app’s runtime compatibility is ensured, the Swift language itself will continue to evolve, and the binary interface will also change. To be safe, all components of your app should be built with the same version of Xcode and the Swift compiler to ensure that they work together.

Source: [Swift Blog - Compatibility](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=2)

I am not sure that you have control over this. A good bet would be to hit the devforums to see if the Swift creators can shed some more light.